# How to make pop up windows when long press button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to know how can I make a pop up window when long press button. 
I can't find any solution.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bialy, welcome to StackOverflow. When you make a question, you must post some code that you've already tried. Don't expect us to do everything for you

Answer (score 1):

I can t see the window that you want to pop.
Maybe you want to show a DialogFragment which will pop in the center of the screen?
For longPress event use

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a gesture detector, something like the example below:

```
GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```